# Configure VisualVM for SSL through JMX

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jmx, visualvm

I have succeeded in establishing connection without SSL with the following command:

java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false DemoApp

But how do I connect through SSL? I have created a self signed certificate certreq.csr. How do I use this to establish SSL connection from VisualVM. The official documentation is not clear. Please advise me on the steps.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/monitor-java-jmx) blog link seems to explain in good detail. Does it help?

Comment: I have setup the server side with the SSL connection. But I dont know how to configure VisualVM to adapt to that. As soon as I click on the Node shown in VisualVM it asks for a username and password. What do I give?

Comment: @Kalpa-W I'm late in this game but just replace `jconsole` by `jvisualvm` in the blog.